# Windows Phone 8 SDK crash, mainboard issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sdk, windows-phone-8

Today i tryed to install wp8 sdk and it installed successfully. but when i'm trying to open visual studio my pc going crash and restart every time. I think its mainboard v-hiper problem or something else. my pc informations

Packard Bell TJ75
CPU : I5 430M
Ram : 3 GB
Graphics : HD 5650 1 GB
BIOS : Phoenix Tec. LTD

how can i fix that problem ?

-Thanks,
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Starting Visual Studio has nothing to do with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

What is the crash?  A bluescreen?  And what codes?  Does system event log say anything interesting?

I don't think Visual Studio will try to start the phone emulator until you actually try to debug a phone project in it, so I don't see the immediate connection to Hyper-V.

Does your system crash when you open Visual Studio with no active project?  That might absolve Hyper-V.

Alternatively, can you create some other virtual machine image (e.g, from Ubuntu or another Windows), and try booting that one?  If your host machine crashes when you do that, then it would implicate Hyper-V.

Windows can crash if it gets too tight on system RAM, and 3G of RAM is not very generous.  Both Visual Studio and Hyper-V use a lot of RAM, so you might indeed have problems running them both at the same time.

Comment: Its just shutdown pc when i press visual studio icon. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774672/trying-to-install-windows-phone-sdk-8-0-crashes-my-windows-8-pc its same here. Maybe my visual studio is 32bit it can be reason of crash ?

Comment: there is no 32/64 bit version of vs i think, i will check virtual machine